# Enterprise Scale Landing Zone - CAF - Apply/Create Policies

Tags: azure, terraform

I am using below link to create/assign Standard Azure policies for my Management Groups. The problem is my org. has already created Management Groups and Subscriptions manually using Azure Portal. Can i still create / apply policies using ESLZ TF code and apply to these manually created Management groups using TF code:

```
https://github.com/Azure/terraform-azurerm-caf-enterprise-scale
```

When i see the code archetype (policy) is very tightly coupled to MG creation ?

locals.management_groups.tf:

```
"${local.root_id}-landing-zones" = {
  archetype_id   = "es_landing_zones"
  parameters     = local.empty_map
  access_control = local.empty_map
}
```

archetype_id  is the policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The enterprise scale example follows what they call a ["supermodule approach"](https://aztfmod.github.io/documentation/docs/module/module-intro/).

The example from `locals.management_groups.tf` that you posted there is just the configuration layer of the module. If you want CAF to adopt an existing management group instead of creating a new one, you have to `terraform import` it. That requires you to know the resource address, which you can derive from the  the actual resource definition.

So you're looking for `resource "azurerm_management_group"` and that's in `resources.management_groups.tf`. That file declares multiple management group resources `level_1` to `level_6`, and they're using `for_each` to generate the resources from the module's configuration model.

So after you've *somehow* traced your way through the modules' configuration model and determined where you want your existing management group to end up in the CAFs model, you can run an import as described in [terraform's docs](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/import#example-import-into-resource-configured-with-for_each) and the [azurerm provider's docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/management_group#import) like this:

```
terraform import azurerm_management_group.level_3["my-root-demo-corp"] providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/group1
```

However, even though all of that is technically possible, I'm not sure this is a good approach. The enterprise scale supermodule configuration model is super idiosyncratic to trace through - it's stated goal is to replace "infrastructure as code" with "infrastructure as data". You may find one of the approaches described in [Azure Landing Zone for existing Azure infrastructure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70091145/azure-landing-zone-for-existing-azure-infrastructure/72990059#72990059) more practical for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You *could*  [import](https://www.terraform.io/cli/import) the deployed environment into the TF state and proceed from there.

However, do you see an absolute necessity ? IMO, setting up the LZ is a one-time activity. However, one can argue that ensuring compliance across active & DR LZs is a good use-case for a TF based LZ deployment.

Comment: Sorry, not clear to me. Any example to explain ?

Comment: Are you saying import the MG / Subscription in the .tfstate file which is already created and then run the ESLZ CAF code ? Do i need to modify the CAF code same as my MG / Subscription structure ? And once i run it , it will take the MG / Subscription from .tfstate and create/set policies defined in ESLZ code ?

Comment: (1) The CAF docs mention that it is an opinionated way of deploying LZ : https://github.com/Azure/terraform-azurerm-caf-enterprise-scale#overview
Not sure how much your org's implementation diverges from the recommendation in the CAF project. I'm assuming quite a lot.


(2) If somehow both your implementation and the CAF match , you can reuse the modules in the CAF project. Else , the .tf files need to be restructured.

Comment: When you say .tf files need to be restructured , can you help understand me for my example where MG / subscriptions are already created and i need to define / set the arche_type(policies) using ESLZ TF code , the way i understand is i need to import my already created MGs/Subscription and then run the CAF code so that it build Azure policy on top of it ?